# VBA : Adding object to a collection increases memory usage

Tags: vba, excel, memory, collections

I don't like asking questions in forums like that, because I believe that every question was asked before me, so I just use the search. But now I feel myself a little dumb cause it's the first time I didn't find any answers.

I have a simple question based on a piece of code :

```
Dim demo_1, demo_2 As Variant 'declare the variables
Dim DataCollection As Collection 'declare the collection
Set DataCollection = New Collection 'define the collection
demo_1 = import_demo(1, nb_var) 'load first dataset (+250 mb of memory)
demo_2 = import_demo(2, nb_var) 'load second dataset (+250 mb of memory)
```

So, in total, my program uses 500 mb of memory. Now I want to fill my collection with references to this objects :

```
DataCollection.Add demo_1 'adding reference to a collection (+250 mb of memory Why??)
DataCollection.Add demo_2 'adding reference to a collection (+250 mb of memory Why??)
```

So I repeat my question : "Why the ---- ?" Sorry.

Should adding an object to a collection increase memory usage in VBA, because I'm clearly not cloning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `import_demo(1, nb_var)` function is returning an Array. Adding an array to the collection adds a **copy** of the array. If your function returns a 250MB array, then every copy of that array will add another 250MB.

See this simplified example:

```
Sub test()

  Dim coll As Collection
  Set coll = New Collection

  Dim arr As Variant
  arr = Array(1, 2, 3)

  'Add the array to the collection (makes a copy)
  coll.Add arr

  'Change the ooriginal array
  arr(0) = 4

  Debug.Print coll(1)(0), arr(0) 'Prints 1,4

End Sub
```

But it sounds like you want to work with references. For that, your function will need to return an object/class instance, before you add it to the collection.

If your function is intended to return a `Range`, your assignment to `demo_1 = import_demo(1, nb_var)` is *implicitly* calling the `Range.[_Default]` property (which is equivalent to `Range.Value`). In order to return the `Range` **object**, you need to use the `Set` keyword: `Set demo_1 = import_demo(1, nb_var)`

Comment: Thank you. That was clear. Can you recommend some literature or articles about that kind of information you helped me with ?

Comment: if you declare variables with the right type instead variant, things get less messy.